# strange method definition in Typescript class

Tags: angular, heroku, typescript

I'm following along this heroku tutorial and in this section https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api#create-the-contact-list-template-and-component there is class listing of ContactListComponent

There's function

```
  private getIndexOfContact = ( contactId : String ) => {
    return this.contacts.findIndex( (contact) => { return contact._id === contactId; } );
  }
```

that is used like that:

```
deleteContact = (contactId: String) => {
var idx = this.getIndexOfContact(contactId);
if (idx !== -1) {
  this.contacts.splice(idx, 1);
  this.selectContact(null);
}
return this.contacts;
```

}

Why is the getIndexOfContact implemented like that, instead of ie:

```
  private getIndexOfContact( contactId : String )
  {
    return this.contacts.findIndex( (contact) => { return contact._id === contactId; } );
  }
```

What is this syntax changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which handles the context of `this` better than a regular function.

Example:

```
class A {
      fn1() {
            console.log(this);
      }

      fn2 = () => {
            console.log(this);
      }
}

let a = new A();
setTimeout(a.fn1, 10); // Window
setTimeout(a.fn2, 10); // A {}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fn1()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fn2%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0AsetTimeout(a.fn1%2C%2010)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Window%0AsetTimeout(a.fn2%2C%2010)%3B%20%2F%2F%20A%20%7B%7D))

Another difference between the two is that when using arrow functions as class methods, you don't really get a method but a property on the instance of type function.
That means that the function won't be added to the prototype and won't be added to subclasses.

The compiled js of my example is:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        var _this = this;
        this.fn2 = function () {
            console.log(_this);
        };
    }
    A.prototype.fn1 = function () {
        console.log(this);
    };
    return A;
}());
```

As you can see `fn1` is assigned to the prototype while `fn2` is assigned to the instance in the constructor.

---

#### Edit

A lot of people will say that using arrow functions as class methods is good practice because it keeps the context of `this` for the function, but they are rarely talking about the downsides, so here it is:

```
class B extends A {
      fn1() {
            console.log("B.fn1");
            super.fn1();
      }

      fn2 = () => {
            console.log("B.fn2");
            super.fn2(); // error: Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword
      }
}
```

There's a way around that of course:

```
class B extends A {
      private oldFn2 = this.fn2;

      constructor() {
            super();      
      }

      fn1() {
            console.log("B.fn1");
            super.fn1();
      }

      fn2 = () => {
            console.log("B.fn2");
            this.oldFn2();
      }
}
```

But that's way too much work to be able to call super.

Comment: Strange that even in TS this JS behaviour has been unchanged. So, because of the "this" issue, would you recommend to always use the arrow function syntax for methods in TS?

Comment: I don't use arrow functions as methods at all, if I need to I use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the right `this`. This is because arrow functions don't handle inheritance well.  But for private methods like in your example it should work well

Comment: Edited my answer with an example of what I meant

Comment: @NitzanTomer Is there a good reason to use `bind` rather than a lambda function as wrapper? All benchmarks suggest to use lambda functions...

Comment: @Paleo Well, I guess that it's more of a personal taste, but I can think of two reasons: (1) Wrapping will end up with 2 function invocations while bind ends up with only one.  (2) Bind also lets you bind arguments and returns a function that expects the rest, that's something I find very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax changing is a recommended solution to avoid getting issues when using "this" keyword calling per example the declared function as a callback function.

I had a lot of trouble using the "normal" style way, and after using always the solution " = () =>  { ..." in my projects the problems were gone.